# Submenu is not opening on menu hover

Tags: css, jsp, menu, submenu

i am trying to open a submenu on menu hover but it's not working, any one have idea why that is behaving like that ?
submenu also display upon a menu.
and submenu should be open in right side of menu on hover.

Below is my code

```
<ul class="left_menu">        

                <li class="odd"><a href="#">kkk</a>
                    <ul class="smenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="even"><a href="#">bbb</a>
                    <ul class="smenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

   </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.left_menu{
width:180px;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
list-style:none;
}
ul.left_menu li{
margin:0px;
list-style:none;

}
ul.left_menu li.odd a{
width:166px;height:25px;display:block; border-bottom:1px #e4e4e4 dashed;
text-decoration:none;color:#504b4b;padding:0 0 0 14px; line-height:25px;
}

ul.left_menu li.odd:hover
{
    display:block;
    color: #FFB03B;
}

ul.left_menu li.even:hover
{
    display:block;
    color: #FFB03B;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CSS to this:

```
ul.left_menu{
width:180px;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
list-style:none;
}
ul.left_menu li{
margin:0px;
list-style:none;

}
ul.left_menu li.odd a{
width:166px;height:25px;display:block; border-bottom:1px #e4e4e4 dashed;
text-decoration:none;color:#504b4b;padding:0;
line-height:25px;
}
.smenu{
display:none
}
ul.left_menu li.odd:hover .smenu
{
display:block;
color: #FFB03B;
}

ul.left_menu li.even:hover .smenu
{
display:block;
color: #FFB03B;
}
```

Comment: @ Ganesh Pandhere - Sir It works but problem is that when i hover on menu, it opens below of it not in right side and all css styles also applied in submenu also like border bottom dashed etc. for that what i will have to do ?

Answer (score 1):

First set the submenu invisible.

```
ul.left_menu ul {
  display: none;
}
```

Then instead of:

```
ul.left_menu li.odd:hover
{
    display:block;
    color: #FFB03B;
}
```

use:

```
ul.left_menu li.odd:hover ul
{
    display:block;
    color: #FFB03B;
}
```